# Flutter resize container Programatically

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a container where i want change it size programmatically depending on the offset from the scroll controller , i have tried this equation . it gives me a fine solution but it has some mistakes that would change the size randomly.

`(12 - (widget.height / d))`

```
other working function 

 height = d.floor() < 5 ? widget.value : max(250, (height! - d) % 30);
      width = d.floor() < 5 ? widget.width : max(150, (width! - d) % 30);
```

it works for some gesture events and none for other events.

is there a better solution to change it and get a smooth animation between two values like 400 and 150.

i was having an equation but i lost it .

Comment: can you include sample full snippet. & I hope you can remove js when it is flutter